# How can I find methods calling a particular method and then catching a particular exeption in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, search

I know that you can do ctrl-shift-g to find all calls to a particular method.

My question is: Is there any more advanced search or way to find all calls to a particular method, and in THOSE methods, find the ones that catch a particular exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with regex, you could try to use the regular expression option in the File Search dialog.

e.g. the search pattern

```
try[\s]*?\{[^\}]*?alpha\(\);[^\{]*?IllegalStateException
```

would find all calls to the alpha() function that were caught by IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is.

The best way to do that I can think of (in the UI) would be to do your search, do a search for the exception you're catching and compare both lists. Painful.